# Best class design to Send XML and Receive Response in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, tcp

I would like to send an XML message, and receive a response from a server and decode it. 
That's my class design approach, I would like to know the best design for that thing.

```
     class XMLRequest  extends EventDispatcher
     {
        private var m_data:XML;
        private var m_xmlString:String;

        public function XMLRequest(){ m_data = null;} 

        public function setRequest(xmlString:String):Boolean
        {

            if(xmlString)
            {
              m_data = new XML(xmlString);
              trace("Request --" + m_xmlString);
              return true;
            }

            return false;
        }   

     }


 class XMLResponse  extends EventDispatcher
 {
    private m_xmlString:String;

    public function XMLResponse(){ m_data = null;} 

    public function getResponse(data:XML):String
    {
        if(data)
        {
          m_xmlString = data.toString();
          trace("Repsonse --" + m_xmlString);
          return m_xmlString;
        }

        return " ";
    }
```

then I will have a class Client, that sends and receives the response. 
Is that a good approach or not ?

Comment: Since you tagged this question as Flex; I recommend using the HTTPService class; which will natively turn the server response into an XML Object and is very well documented: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/mxml/HTTPService.html .  I Do not understand what the code you provided is intending to accomplish; or how you think it is supposed to integrate with a remote service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend use class disign like adobe Loader. Also, I recommend use native class XML instead of String

XMLLoader.as

```
package {
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;

    [Event(type="flash.events.Event", name="complete")]
    public interface XMLLoader extends IEventDispatcher {
        function load(requestXML:XML):void;

        function getResponseXML():XML;
    }
}
```

XMLLoaderTester.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class XMLLoaderTester extends Sprite {
        public function XMLLoaderTester() {
            var loader:XMLLoader; //dont forget instantiate
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onResponse);

            var requestXML:XML = <command>getData</command>;
            loader.load(requestXML);
        }

        private function onResponse(event:Event):void {
            var loader:XMLLoader = XMLLoader(event.target);
            trace(loader.getResponseXML());
        }
    }
}
```